# Bootstrap 5 underline default changed?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 4 i understand it set the default text-decoration to be none.

But using Bootstrap 5 if i just add a raw anchor tag it is now showing both the blue writing and underline.

I was looking to only show the undelrine upon hovering. Is this something bootstrap 5 changed in the release? I cannot find any documentation stating it.

Currently i use:

```
    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: inherit
}
```

but this is also affecting any buttons as links e.g.

```
<a href="{% url 'answer-create' question.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-2 py-0">Answer</a>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, As of Bootstrap 5 alpha1 the [migration docs state](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#typography):

> "Links are underlined by default (not just on hover), unless they’re part of specific components"

You could create a special class like this:

```
.text-underline-hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.text-underline-hover:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

<a href="#" class="text-underline-hover">Link</a>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/3tRMSkoshD)

***Or***, if you want it to apply to all anchors except for those that contain a `class=` attribute use:

```
a:not([class]) {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:not([class]):hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This will not effect `btn`, only links without `class` will underline on hover.

Comment: thanks, is there a best practice to enable just on hover? I have edited my question above to show what i currently do and works although it causes the link buttons to also be affected which is not what i want.

Comment: I don't know the rationale behind this decision. You can [open an issue on GH](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues) if you'd like more information.

Comment: My update provides a solution for you. This way btn will not be affected. See: https://codeply.com/p/3tRMSkoshD

Comment: For large websites, that might have code link this `<a class="mb-4" ...`, neither solutions work well. The latter solution will leave it underlined and the first solution will involve finding and tweaking all those links. This answer is a good start though. Let me try to tweak the second solution and post it as a new answer.

Comment: I have used this approach but only in specific places by creating a new CSS class "no-underline" along with the "hover" part.

Answer (score 11):

**All-in-one solution**

This CSS code for Bootstrap 5 won't underline your `<a ...>` links (unless hovered over):

- even if they have another class like `mb-4` etc
- unless they have the `btn` class, in which case they stay untouched.

Code to copy paste into your CSS file:

```
/* Bootstrap 5 tweak: do not underline links unless hovered over */
a:not([class*="btn"]) {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:not([class*="btn"]):hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Proof:

```css
/* Simulate Bootstrap 5 CSS */
a { 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover { 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a.btn {
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
a.btn:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   background-color:  #ccc;
}

/* Bootstrap 5 tweak: do not underline links unless hovered over */
a:not([class*="btn"]) {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:not([class*="btn"]):hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="foo.html">An a link without class</a><br/>
<br/>
<a href="foo.html" class="cool">An a link with class cool</a><br/>
<br/>
<a href="foo.html" class="btn">An a link with class btn</a>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for links in [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#nav) which have `nav-link` or `dropdown-item` classes. They are still underlined.

Comment: The answer clearly stated it's specifically for `btn` classes, so you could just simply add more selectors accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

If you are compiling the Sass in your project, you can set the anchor link style using Bootstrap's Sass variables. It's part of their Reboot styles.

Set the following to only see underlines when you hover over a link.

```
$link-decoration: none;
$link-hover-decoration: underline;
```

[View relevant Bootstrap source here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_reboot.scss#L243-L251)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution! All others are kind of 'workarounds'. 

Answer (score 3):

As the default anchor is now underlined, defining custom CSS rules is tricky as these rules will interfere with components (for example navbars, dropdowns, ...).

The official solution i think will be using `.text-decoration-none` on all the anchors. It's a bit annoying but it's explicit and, we all hope, future-proof. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<a>` tag also has the `btn` class that's why you get this behaviour.

```
class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-2 py-0"
```

Because buttons in bootstrap also has `btn` class. That's why with your CSS.

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: inherit
}
```

All the buttons with class `btn` also becomes underlined.

**Solution:**

Just remove `btn btn-outline-dark`  from `<a>` and use custom class to style it.

```
<a href="{% url 'answer-create' question.id %}" class="mylink mr-2 py-0">Answer</a>
```

Comment: is there a way to fix this? i need the a's to be underlined on hover but the buttons to remain unaffected.

Comment: :not(class)  can be used

Comment: ok thanks, would this mean that i would no longer be able to use 'btn' without it inheriting the underline on hover above? seems strange as this method would mean bootstrap btn's would now not work as standard.

Comment: Ya whenever we use btn class on a <a> tag there will occur these issues. But we can customize this by adding some additional CSS... Like I mentioned above comment