# Bootstrap 5 underline navbar menu item

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to get the current selected menu within a navbar to be underlined however it isn't working.

My code:

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-item:focus .nav-link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

It seems quite common to have the selected menu link underline or highlighted in some way but I cannot figure out how to achieve this with Bootstrap 5.

Comment: Have you tried adding the class [`text-decoration-underline`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-decoration) to the element?

Comment: I want that on :focus
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp
text-decoration-underline would be always applied if I am not mistaken.

Comment: [Does this answer your question by any chance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480130/8982034)

Comment: No. That's the :focus that interest me, or something with similar result. I can do that very easily with vanilla css but it doesn't work with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply pesudo class `:focus` on .nav-link element

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Somehow this behave like :active It gets underline and yellow after clicking but does not keep it.

Comment: Yeah `:active` is not solution of your problem

Comment: Can you please show me that what do you want to make

Comment: Sorry, I spent some time troubleshooting it and what I actually want is not only :focus but that the underline stays while the user stays on the page. Usually current page or something which is not done in css. In my case I'm using hugo and there's a way to do that. Thank you for your answer though. It helped me find the real problem and your solution is actually right for focus!

Answer (score 2):

Try to override the 'active' class:

`.navbar-nav .active { text-decoration: underline; background-color: yellow; }`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your `css` doesn't affect is because `.nav-item` never get focused..

If you want it to get focused use [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Else, change it to `.nav-link:focus {text-decoration: underline;}` (you don't need even `!important` for that).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentionned to Zain, what I wanted to do was to actually keep the underline while the user is on the selected page (current page) and is not only a focus. Your solution is correct for :focus and helped me find what I really needed.